# LWC internal server error after clicking a button

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, developer

During updating a count value after clicking a button getting some internal server error problem. error details and component details  given below kindly check and help me if you found something ?

```
        Error in updating records An internal server error has occurred
        Error ID: 2065584812-572161 (-97864558)
```

Any help ?

### HTML file

```
<template>
    <lightning-modal-header class = "fontsize">Case Repair Details</lightning-modal-header>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Case" record-id={recordId} onsubmit={handleSubmit} onsuccess={handleSuccess}>
                
            <lightning-modal-footer>
                <lightning-button label="Cancel" onclick={closeModal} class="slds-var-p-right_x-small"></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" disabled={disableBtn}></lightning-button>
            </lightning-modal-footer>
 
</template>
```

### Js FILE

```
import { LightningElement,track, api } from 'lwc';
import {CloseActionScreenEvent} from 'lightning/actions';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import setRaiseRepair from '@salesforce/apex/CaseOperationStatus.RaiseRepairDetails';
import REPAIR_COUNT from "@salesforce/schema/Case.ET_Repair_Count__c";

export default class RaiseRepair extends LightningElement {

@api _recordId;
@api count = REPAIR_COUNT;

    @api set recordId(value) {
        this._recordId = value;
    }
    
    get recordId() {
      return this._recordId;
    }

handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        this.count = this.count+1;
        console.log('Repair Count----->'+this.count);
        setRaiseRepair({repair : this.count}).then(response=>
            {
            if(response) {
                    console.log('Success in updating records',response);
                    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Case Repair',
                        message: 'Case Repair is successfully raised',
                        variant: 'success',
                        mode: 'dismissable'
            
                    });
                    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
                    this.dispatchEvent(new CloseActionScreenEvent());
                    eval("$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();");
                                
                }
            }

      }
}
```

### Apex class

```
public without sharing class CaseOperationStatus {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String RaiseRepairDetails(Id recordId,String repair) {
        List<EmailTemplate> templateObj = [SELECT Id, Subject, Body, HtmlValue, DeveloperName, FolderName, Name, NamespacePrefix FROM EmailTemplate where developerName =: 'EMEA_Template_Sample' LIMIT 1];
        Case record = new Case(Id=recordId, ET_Repair_Count__c = repair, Status = 'Waiting on Submitter'); 

        try {
            update record;
            return 'Success';
         }
        catch(DmlException e) {
            System.debug('The exception occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: currently, setRaiseRepair only has one argument, however, your apex method is expecting two arguments. could you also add another argument ie. _recordId and give it a try?